# How to make main java method simpler in kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, kotlin

I'm using gradle application plugin:

```
apply plugin:'application'
mainClassName = "com.example.MyApplication"
```

Im having following kotlin code for main app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to simplify this code in order not to use `companion object` and `@JvmStatic` annotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [Gradle hello-world example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/hello-world) in the JetBrains/kotlin-examples repo.

To summarize, you can just do this:

```
// src/main/kotlin/demo/helloWorld.kt
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(getGreeting())
}
```

And then in your `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'demo.HelloWorldKt'
```

---

In your specific case, the `mainClassName` would be `com.example.MyApplicationKt` if your filename is `MyApplication.kt`. As for that Kotlin file, it could contain this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication 

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApplication>(*args)
}
```